# How to use a C library that requires a buffer and a struct for the output data in C#

Tags: c#, c, dll, marshalling

I would like to know how to use a C library in my C# console application.

The C library has a .h file that contains this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int16_t coef[16];
    uint16_t gain;
    uint16_t pred_scale;
    int16_t yn1;
    int16_t yn2;

    uint16_t loop_pred_scale;
    int16_t loop_yn1;
    int16_t loop_yn2;
} ADPCMINFO;

DLLEXPORT void encode(int16_t* src, uint8_t* dst, ADPCMINFO* cxt, uint32_t samples);
DLLEXPORT void decode(uint8_t* src, int16_t* dst, ADPCMINFO* cxt, uint32_t samples);
DLLEXPORT void getLoopContext(uint8_t* src, ADPCMINFO* cxt, uint32_t samples);

DLLEXPORT void encodeFrame(int16_t* src, uint8_t* dst, int16_t* coefs, uint8_t one);
DLLEXPORT void correlateCoefs(int16_t* src, uint32_t samples, int16_t* coefsOut);

DLLEXPORT uint32_t getBytesForAdpcmBuffer(uint32_t samples);
DLLEXPORT uint32_t getBytesForAdpcmSamples(uint32_t samples);
DLLEXPORT uint32_t getBytesForPcmBuffer(uint32_t samples);
DLLEXPORT uint32_t getBytesForPcmSamples(uint32_t samples);
DLLEXPORT uint32_t getNibbleAddress(uint32_t samples);
DLLEXPORT uint32_t getNibblesForNSamples(uint32_t samples);
DLLEXPORT uint32_t getSampleForAdpcmNibble(uint32_t nibble);
DLLEXPORT uint32_t getBytesForAdpcmInfo(void);
```

There are two things that I don't know how to fix:

1. The output buffer, I would use an array, but the problem here is that I don't know the output size.
2. The struct, "typedef struct" does not exists in C#, I'm not sure if will be compatible with the internal struct that I've declared in C#

Here's the C# code:

```
class Program
{
    internal struct ADPCMINFO
    {
        internal short[] coef;
        internal ushort gain;
        internal ushort pred_scale;
        internal short yn1;
        internal short yn2;

        internal ushort loop_pred_scale;
        internal short loop_yn1;
        internal short loop_yn2;
    }

    [DllImport("dsptool.dll")]
    public static extern void encode(short[] src, byte[] dst, ADPCMINFO cxt, uint samples);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Ensure that we have arguments
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            //Usage
            if (args[0].ToLower().Contains("help") || args[0].Contains("?"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: <Encode> <InputFile> <OutputFile> <-L> ");
            }
            else
            {
                //Get input params
                if (args.Length >= 3)
                {
                    uint loopStart = 0;
                    string modeApp = args[0].ToLower(), inputFile = args[1].ToLower(), outputFile = args[2].ToLower();
                    bool Looped = args[3] != null;
                    if (Looped)
                    {
                        loopStart = Convert.ToUInt32(args[4]);
                    }

                    //Read wave file
                    if (File.Exists(inputFile) && modeApp.Equals("Encode", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        //Read data
                        WaveFileReader waveReader = new WaveFileReader(inputFile);
                        byte[] byteData = new byte[waveReader.Length];
                        waveReader.Read(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);

                        //Convert byte array to short array
                        short[] pcmData = ConvertByteArrayToShortArray(byteData);

                        //Start encoding
                        byte[] encodedData;
                        ADPCMINFO structInfo = new ADPCMINFO
                        {
                            coef = new short[16]
                        };
                        encode(pcmData, encodedData, structInfo, (uint)pcmData.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static short[] ConvertByteArrayToShortArray(byte[] PCMData)
    {
        short[] samplesShort = new short[PCMData.Length / 2];
        WaveBuffer sourceWaveBuffer = new WaveBuffer(PCMData);
        for (int i = 0; i < samplesShort.Length; i++)
        {
            samplesShort[i] = sourceWaveBuffer.ShortBuffer[i];
        }
        return samplesShort;
    }
}
```

Comment: There appears no way to pass the buffer size in, unless `samples` is the size. What does the documentation say about it? `ADPCMINFO cxt` parameter should be `ref ADPCMINFO cxt`. And `internal short[] coef;` should have the attribute `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]`

Comment: Oh, yes you're right, in the documentation says that we need to calculate the buffer size with getBytesForAdpcmBuffer() Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Charlieface I could finally fix this, here's the code that I've used:

```
class Program
{
    internal struct ADPCMINFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        internal short[] coef;
        internal ushort gain;
        internal ushort pred_scale;
        internal short yn1;
        internal short yn2;

        internal ushort loop_pred_scale;
        internal short loop_yn1;
        internal short loop_yn2;
    }

    [DllImport("dsptool.dll")]
    public static extern void encode(short[] src, byte[] dst, ref ADPCMINFO cxt, uint samples);
    [DllImport("dsptool.dll")]
    public static extern uint getBytesForAdpcmBuffer(uint samples);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Ensure that we have arguments
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            //Usage
            if (args[0].ToLower().Contains("help") || args[0].Contains("?"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: <Encode> <InputFile> <OutputFile> <-L> ");
            }
            else
            {
                //Get input params
                if (args.Length >= 3)
                {
                    uint loopStart = 0;
                    string modeApp = args[0].ToLower(), inputFile = args[1].ToLower(), outputFile = args[2].ToLower();
                    bool Looped = args[3] != null;
                    if (Looped)
                    {
                        loopStart = Convert.ToUInt32(args[4]);
                    }

                    //Read wave file
                    if (File.Exists(inputFile) && modeApp.Equals("Encode", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        //Read data
                        WaveFileReader waveReader = new WaveFileReader(inputFile);
                        byte[] byteData = new byte[waveReader.Length];
                        waveReader.Read(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);

                        //Convert byte array to short array
                        short[] pcmData = ConvertByteArrayToShortArray(byteData);

                        //Start encoding
                        byte[] encodedData = new byte[getBytesForAdpcmBuffer((uint)pcmData.Length)];
                        ADPCMINFO structInfo = new ADPCMINFO();
                        encode(pcmData, encodedData, ref structInfo, (uint)pcmData.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static short[] ConvertByteArrayToShortArray(byte[] PCMData)
    {
        short[] samplesShort = new short[PCMData.Length / 2];
        WaveBuffer sourceWaveBuffer = new WaveBuffer(PCMData);
        for (int i = 0; i < samplesShort.Length; i++)
        {
            samplesShort[i] = sourceWaveBuffer.ShortBuffer[i];
        }
        return samplesShort;
    }
}
```